# How do I change an ASP.NET Identity user's email WITHOUT requiring an email confirmation?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

We have many non-tech-savvy users who find it very challenging to use the regular method of changing their email (click a link on the log-in page, enter their email, check their inbox, click the link in the email to confirm). We would like to allow the site admins to be able to change the emails directly, without requiring the users to do anything.

I realise that this has certain dangers, but we have checks in place to ensure that we are going to use the correct new email.

It seems that if I have the existing user from the database and the modified one from a `<form>` on the admin page, I can just do this...

```
  existingUser.Email = modifiedUser.Email;
  existingUser.NormalizedEmail = modifiedUser.Email.ToUpper();
  existingUser.UserName = modifiedUser.Email;
  existingUser.NormalizedUserName = modifiedUser.Email.ToUpper();
  _appDbContext.Users.Update(existingUser);
  await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This does seem to work (with one caveat, see below), but given that I've never seen recommend this, and every example I've seen creates a token and uses `UserManager.SetEmailAsync`, I'm wondering if I've missed something.

The one caveat that makes me even more suspicious is that once or twice when I've tried the above, it's created a new user with the same details as the existing one, but the new email. I can't reproduce this, so can't say for definite what causes it.

Anyone able to comment on the best way to handle this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can set and confirm the email without sending any  email like this. Use the `UserManager` provided by ASP.NET Core Identity:

```
// set the email on the user, but don't send any email
await _userManager.SetEmailAsync(currentUser, newEmailAddress);

//generate an email confirmation token
var emailConfirmationToken = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(existingUser);

//confirm the new email right away
result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(existingUser, emailConfirmationToken);
```

Comment: I wondered about that, but as the way I showed seemed to work, and didn't require injecting another dependency, I was interested if there were any problems with it.

Comment: Oh okay. If you want to avoid the dependency, then you could mimic what UserManager does at the database level internally in your own code:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d06c029f6a7374920993ee844b7a601121e589c3/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1393

Comment: I've no massive objections to the dependency, but wondered if I needed it. I'd certainly rather inject than copy their code and risk it going out of date. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Just tried your code, and it changed the email and normalisedemail fields in the database, but didn't change the username and normalisedusername fields, so the user can't log in with the new email address. Any idea why? If I'm going to have to set these other two manually, I might as well do them all that way and not bother with the user manager at all.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel - ASP.NET Identity keeps the username as a separate field, you can use the SetUserNameAsync method to update the username as well. I know ASP.NET Identity exposes a login mechanism for the User Name and Email Address, so if you're calling the Username version, that would explain the failure. In my app, the username and the email both store the same value, so I update them both whenever one is updated. In addition to updating the value in the database, the exposed method also updates the security stamp so there is additional behavior happening in the framework under the covers

Comment: Yeah, I originally thought that changing the email would change both, as by default, they are always the same. If I'm going to have to make two calls to do this, I don't see any benefit in using the `UserManager` methods over setting the values manually. Thanks for the reply.